# How to make link in joomla

Tags: joomla

hi i am new in joomla.I need the dynamic link in view file.

//no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

// include the helper file
require_once(dirname(**FILE**).DS.'helper.php');

// get a parameter from the module's configuration

$userCount = 5;

// get the items to display from the helper
$items = ModNewHelper::getItems($userCount);

//link of the component

// include the template for display
require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_new'));

this is main file

/**
 * @author Raju Gautam
 * @copyright 2011
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

class ModNewHelper
{
    /**
     * Returns a list of post items
    */
    public function getItems($userCount)
    {
        // get a reference to the database
        $db = &JFactory::getDBO();

```
    // get a list of $userCount randomly ordered users 
    $query = 'SELECT name,id FROM `#__hello` ORDER BY ordering LIMIT ' . $userCount  . '';

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $items = ($items = $db->loadObjectList())?$items:array();

    return $items;
} //end getItems
```

} //end ModHelloWorld2Helper

this is helper file

defined('*JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); // no direct access 
 echo JText::*('Latest News'); 
//echo "

```
"; print_r($items); exit;
```

foreach ($items as $item) {

`<a href="#"> echo JText::sprintf($item->name); </a>`

} this is view file

I need the link on echo JText::sprintf($item->name); this line. can i helped please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`echo "<a href='".JRoute::_($item->link, false)."'>". JText::sprintf($item->name)."</a>";`

`JRoute` will take care of routing also, if routing is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

change your this line from view file:

```
<a href="#"> echo JText::sprintf($item->name); </a>
```

to :

```
echo "<a href='".$item->link."'>". JText::sprintf($item->name)."</a>";
```

assuming, `link` is the field name of your link else change it according to the field name you've used for link. this may help, i guess .. good luck with it.